# Set AutoCompleteInput to suggest list of words

Tags: html, vue.js, input, autocomplete, autosuggest

In my Vue project I found that setting the id to "autocompleteInput" made it suggest prevously typed words then the input field is focused:

```
                <input
                  id="autocompleteInput"
                />
```

But how do I make it suggest a list of words by default?
E.g. how to give the autocompleteInput a list like this: ["Germany", "France", "Spain"] and then it suggests those?

I dont know why setting input id to "autocompleteInput" gives previously typed suggestions but it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Found this simple solution:

```
              <input
                  list="browsers"
                />
                <datalist id="browsers">
                  <option value="Chrome"></option>
                  <option value="Firefox"></option>
                </datalist>
```